# KMP prefix table running time

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, string-matching

I wrote a code for filling the prefix table for KMP. It is small variation of this [algorithm](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=knuth-morris-pratt). I'm unable to convince myself that this algorithm/implementation runs in O(n) time. I have hard time figuring out the second recursive call affect on the total run time. Any help?

```
    public void fillFailTable(int[] failTable,String p){
        failTable[failTable.length-1] = preLength(failTable,p);
    }

    private int preLength(int[] failTable,String s){

        if(s.length() == 1){
            return 0;
        }
        int n = s.length();
        int k = preLength(failTable,s.substring(0,n-1));

        failTable[n-2] = k;

        if(s.charAt(k) == s.charAt(n-1)){
            return k+1;
        }else{
            return preLength(failTable,s.substring(n-1-k));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use profiler - here, take a look: http://pawel-michalski-javnie.blogspot.com/2012/07/jvisualvm.html

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty interesting (I'm still wondering why no one smarter than me answered this yet). Please take this explanation with a grain of salt as I'm not 100% sure this is even close to being correct (although I can tell you for 100% that this method runs in O(n) since that's what they told me at the University years ago but they didn't bother explaining it though, d'uh, so I had to come up with it on my own).

Ok so let's start with a very basic example of s.length = 2. Two things to mention beforehand:

- during each example lets only worry about the worst case scenarion, since we're interested in Big Oh, meaning we enter the second preLength() method.
- we can observe, when looking for the Big Oh, that "k" (and the values returned by preLength()) in this code will always be 0, which you will notice in the images below and which is *really* important.

### s.length == 2

We first enter the first preLength() method (lets call it *), which is now invoked with s.length = 1 and return immediately with a 0. Now since we're considering only the worst case scenario (meaning s.charAt(k) != s.charAt(n-1)) we enter the second preLength() with also a string of length = 1 (since n=2 and k=0). This one also returns a 0 immediately to our *. This ends our method invocation. In total we had 3 method invocations. Our * and two preLength(). Here's an image:

[image]

### s.length == 3

Now lets look at an example with a starting s.length = 3. As you can notice we immediately invoke a preLength() with s.length = 2 and, from our previous example, we know that this one need 3 method invocations. Now we need to remember that when the method preLength(2) returns this time it returns to our native preLength(3) which will now invoke again preLength(2) (the one in the else) which will again need 3 method invocations. So in total we need 2*3+1 method invocations. This gives us 7. Again, here's an image (a circle is an invocation of preLength with a string of the length shown in the circle):

[image]

### Conclusions

Now as you can see all those method invocations are symmetrical - and that is because our `k` is **always** equal to 0 which means that the second preLengt() will be invoked with a string of the same size as the first one - and we can see how many of them we will need for `s.length = m` when we know how many of them we need for `m-1` since `f(m) = 2*f(m-1)+1` where `f(m)` is the function telling us how many method invocations we need to compute the table for a string of size `m`. This works since as I said before the method invocations are symmetrical (**that's because in worst case k=0 always and preLenght() always return 0**, hence the 2* and we need to add 1 method invocation, the first one we ever invoke).

So basically with each incrementation of our input (size of `m`) the computational time grows 2 times plus one (2*m+1) which to my understanding means that this method is, in worst case, O(n).

As I said please do take this with a grain of salt but I hope this makes some sense :)